# How do I split a vector into a table with columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector with some missing data, and I would like to convert this to a dataframe with 4 columns.

I have two questions for this:
1. How do I split one column into multiple columns
2. How do I account for missing data

Data:

```
# Create similar data
a <- c("building #1 Addr 01 Zip 99999","20 sq ft","23","-33 rev",
       "building #2 Addr 02 Zip 99999","30 sq ft","23",
       "building #3 Addr 03 Zip 99999","40 sq ft",
       "building #4 Addr 04 Zip 99999","50 sq ft","23","-33 rev",
       "building #5 Addr 05 Zip 99999","-33 rev",
       "building #6 Addr 06 Zip 99999","70 sq ft","23","-33 rev",
       "building #7 Addr 07 Zip 99999","80 sq ft",
       "building #8 Addr 08 Zip 99999","90 sq ft","23","-33 rev",
       "building #9 Addr 09 Zip 99999","00 sq ft")
```

I would like to create a table that looks like this:

```
 # Desired output

 building_id <- c("building #1 Addr 01 Zip 99999",
                  "building #2 Addr 02 Zip 99999",
                  "building #3 Addr 03 Zip 99999",
                  "building #4 Addr 04 Zip 99999",
                  "building #5 Addr 05 Zip 99999",
                  "building #6 Addr 06 Zip 99999",
                  "building #7 Addr 07 Zip 99999",
                  "building #8 Addr 08 Zip 99999",
                  "building #9 Addr 09 Zip 99999")
   sqft<- c("20 sq ft","30 sq ft","40 sq ft","50 sq ft","","70 sq ft",
   "80 sq ft","90 sq ft","00 sq ft")
    employees <- c("23","23","","23","","23","","23","")
   revenue <- c("-33 rev","","","-33 rev","","-33 rev","","-33 rev","")

   df <- data.frame(building_id,sqft,employees,revenue)


building_id                   sqft        employees revenue
building #1 Addr 01 Zip 99999 20 sq ft    23        -33 rev
building #2 Addr 02 Zip 99999 30 sq ft    23        
building #3 Addr 03 Zip 99999 40 sq ft                  
building #4 Addr 04 Zip 99999 50 sq ft    23        -33 rev
building #5 Addr 05 Zip 99999                           
building #6 Addr 06 Zip 99999 70 sq ft    23        -33 rev
building #7 Addr 07 Zip 99999 80 sq ft                  
building #8 Addr 08 Zip 99999 90 sq ft    23        -33 rev
building #9 Addr 09 Zip 99999 00 sq ft
```

Comment: I am open to feedback on how to most effectively ask this type of a question - please let me know how I can clarify if possible

Comment: You can use `grep` with `lapply`.e.g., `df$building_id<-grep("[building]", building_id,value=TRUE)`

Comment: @ Metrics - thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll need to do some research on how to do this (the lapply part)

Comment: @clevelandfrowns I think building #5 also have the revenue as -33 rev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `split` the vector ("a") into a list ("lst") based on creating a grouping variable from finding the presence of "building" in the vector
 (`grepl('^building',..)`.  `grep` the list elements in a loop (`sapply(`) for individual elements ('building', 'sq ft' etc.).  If it results in a length of '0' (not present), then assign NA or else the `grep` value, `unlist`, and `rbind` to create the dataset `d1`.

```
lst <- split(a, cumsum(grepl('^building', a)))

d1 <-  do.call(rbind.data.frame,lapply(lst, function(x) 
     unlist(sapply(c('building', 'sq ft', '^\\d+$', 'rev'), function(y) {
      x1 <- grep(y, x, value=TRUE)
      if(!length(x1)) NA else x1}))))
colnames(d1) <- c("building_id","sqft","employees","revenue")
d1
#                    building_id     sqft employees revenue
#1 building #1 Addr 01 Zip 99999 20 sq ft        23 -33 rev
#2 building #2 Addr 02 Zip 99999 30 sq ft        23    <NA>
#3 building #3 Addr 03 Zip 99999 40 sq ft      <NA>    <NA>
#4 building #4 Addr 04 Zip 99999 50 sq ft        23 -33 rev
#5 building #5 Addr 05 Zip 99999     <NA>      <NA> -33 rev
#6 building #6 Addr 06 Zip 99999 70 sq ft        23 -33 rev
#7 building #7 Addr 07 Zip 99999 80 sq ft      <NA>    <NA>
#8 building #8 Addr 08 Zip 99999 90 sq ft        23 -33 rev
#9 building #9 Addr 09 Zip 99999 00 sq ft      <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Apologies for not including the expected output - hope that correction helps make it easier to understand

Comment: Thank you so much for the help - this gets me closer, however it still seems to break for the rows that have missing data. I can try to work around this

Comment: wow that worked beautifully!!!! There are quite a few tricks in there that I will need to try to understand - but this made my day. Thank you sir!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @clevelandfrowns No problem.  I added some explanation in the post